# how to display all the values in a row by just clicking only one of the values in that row

Tags: php, html, gridview, view

The situation is that when I click the row it will direct me to the "view page" or clicking the "update button" will direct me to the "update window". Now I want the delete and update button to be in one row with the name and address values.

I have tried to align it and there's no problem with clicking the row, it directs me to the "view page" but every time i click the "update button", it pop up two windows, that is the "view window" and "update window" wherein it should only be the "update window" that will pop-out.

so how can I make it that the update page will not affect the view page.

here is the link picture of my work:

(this is not yet aligned because when I try i got the problem above) http://www.fileden.com/files/2011/7/27/3174077/My_Documents/a.JPG

Here is its code:

```
<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Principal Page</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

function pop_up(id) {
var newWind = window.open( "view_principal.php?id="+id, "myWindow", 
"status = 1, height = 200, width = 400, resizable = 0" );
}

function goModify(id)
{
window.location.href = "modify_principal.php?id=" + id;
}

function goDelete(id)
{
var answer = confirm ("Are you sure you want to delete?")

if (answer)
   window.location.href = "delete_principal.php?id=" + id;
}

function ChangeColor(tableRow, highLight)
{
if (highLight)
{
  tableRow.style.backgroundColor = '#66CCFF';
}
else
{
 tableRow.style.backgroundColor = '#69F';
}

 }

 function DoLink(theUrl)
{
document.location.href = theUrl;
}

</script>



</head>

<body>

<p>
<?php
require_once ('include/config.php');
require_once ('include/opendb.php');
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM principal");
echo "</br>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<div class='divMainTable'>";
echo "<table border='1' >
  <tr class = 'headertable'>
    <th width = '200'> Name</th>
    <th> Address</th>
 </tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
echo "<tr onclick = 'pop_up($row[principal_ID])');return false;'      onmouseover='ChangeColor(this, true);' onmouseout='ChangeColor(this, false);'>";


echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['address']."</td>"; 

echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
echo "</div>";

echo "<div class='divSecondTable'>";
echo "<table class='updatetable' border='1'>";
echo "<tr class='dataTable'>";
echo "<td align='center'>"."<input type='button' name='update' value='Update' 
onClick='goModify($row[principal_ID])');>"."</td>";

echo "<td align='center'>"."<input type='button' name='delete' value='Delete' 
onClick='goDelete($row[principal_ID])');>"."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
echo "</div>";

}



?>

<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="add_principal.php">
<p class="add_option">
<input type="submit" name="add" id="button" value="ADD" />
</p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason both windows pop up is because of event bubbling.  The event on the input tag is fired then the event on the tr tag is fired.

You need to stop propagation with

```
event.stopPropagation()
```

in your functions.  This is actually easier to do if you bind your events in your script rather than writing inline event handlers.

UPDATE:

In your example because you are passing arguments, you also need to pass the event object.

So you inline event needs event added to the arguments, and should read like this:

```
<input type="button" name="update" value="Update" onClick="goModify(event, $row[principal_ID]);">
```

then in your function you need to accept the event so your function now becomes:

```
function goModify(event, id)
{
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.cancelBubble = true; // for ie
    window.location.href = "modify_principal.php?id=" + id;
}
```

You would do the same for the delete button and js function.

Comment: can you show me sample code using that? I am totally a beginner.. thanks